# SUBSTRING() / MID() Statement in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, mysql, sql, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I'm trying to implement the following, pretty simple, query:

```
WHERE
  a.first_table IS NULL
  AND a.second_table IS NOT NULL
  AND SUBSTRING(b.third_table,5,2) = @plan_year;
```

As you might guess the first two statements are not really a problem. I currently fail at implementing the SUBSTRING() via Zend, as I want to keep the code DB-System neutral.
Is there any way to do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about to use [**SUBSTR**](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-substr-function.php) instead of `SUBSTRING`?

```
WHERE
  a.first_table IS NULL
  AND a.second_table IS NOT NULL
  AND SUBSTR(b.third_table,5,2) = @plan_year;
```

Comment: But then again, isn't SUBSTR() php and invalid as SQL-Statement ?

Comment: No, it's MySQL function, check updated answer with link to documentation.

Comment: Oh... I see... Allow me the question: Why is there the MID() function ? And still, this doesn't seam Platform independent in this way ?